# Can I get my Microkorg sound (patch) on my digital piano?

Tags: midi, keyboard, synthesizer, midi-controller-keyboard

I have a [Korg Microkorg](https://www.korg.com/fr/products/synthesizers/microkorg/) synth which is a really fun synthesizer for a beginner like me. I like making patches (tones) and exploring the different possibilites. However, it's a bit annoying to use because the keyboard is very limited, it's basically only there so you can quickly test your patch before exporting it to a project on your computer.

I would love to control my Microkorg using my digital piano ([Kawai ES110](https://www.kawai-global.com/product/es110/)). I've already done it, plugging the piano as a midi controller allows you to use the keyboard to get sounds from the synth. However, the Microkorg doesn't have an audio output. When I do this, I have to use headphones, or an external amp.

This is the configuration that I have:

```
Keyboard --midi cable--> Microkorg --audio cable--> Headphones or amp
```

I use my digital piano in my living room, and I don't really like to have a lot of cables, headphones, amps etc there. I would love it if I could plug in the microkorg discreetly in a way that would allow me to use the keyboard from my piano and get the synth's sound directly out of the piano.

This is what I would like to have:

```
Keyboard --midi cable--> Microkorg --
^                                   |
|___________________________________|
```

Is it possible? I'm guessing not, because there is not audio input on the piano. However there might be some functionality that I'm not aware of.

Comment: OT: it's "digital" piano, not "numeric"; I suppose you probably speak French, for which the "numérique" term is indiscriminately used for both "numeric" and "digital", which have different meanings in English: the former is used for *anything* related to numbers, including non-integer numbers (rationals, fractions, etc), while the latter is for systems using *discrete* numbers, normally based on *binary* digits. When dealing with electronic devices, "digital" is the preferred word, except when talking about *actual* numeric values (mathematical conversions, data types, etc).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Korg has line out, but the Kawai doesn't have line in, so you'd need a separate amp/speakers.

https://www.korg.com/uk/products/synthesizers/microkorg/page_3.php

https://www.kawai-global.com/product/es110/